# extract first 3 char to mutable string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablestring

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[str appendString: @"ab cd efghil mnopq rstuvz"];
//my test 
[str deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(2, [str length] -1)];
```

I would extract the first 3 char.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, since you are not happy with the answers.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is that you want your mutable string to become just the first three characters, then this should work (hat tip @EmptyStack):

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[str appendString: @"ab cd efghil mnopq rstuvz"];
[str setString:[str substringToIndex:2]];
```

Alternatively, your proposed solution isn't far off:

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[str appendString: @"ab cd efghil mnopq rstuvz"];
[str deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(3, [str length] -3)];
```

---

If you're question is that you want the first 3 characters in one string, and the remainder left in the mutable string then this is what you want:

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[str appendString: @"ab cd efghil mnopq rstuvz"];
NSMutableString *first3Chars = [[[str substringToIndex:3] mutableCopy] autorelease];
[str deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];
```

Comment: Mind accepting the answer, and also telling us which one you chose?